# Render node with multiple display modes by extending its path

Tags: drupal-8

Using Drupal 8.

Drupal 8 i can create an additional display-mode (like *teaser*) (`admin/structure/display-modes/view`), I called it *Fullscreen*

Would it be possible to route it somehow to `/node/_NID_/fullscreen`
to get a output of that single node in that *Fullscreen*-display-mode?

Would be even better if it would also work with Pathauto: 
e.g.

`/_NODETITLE_` -> node rendered as display mode *Full*

`/_NODETITLE_/fullscreen` -> node renderes as display mode *Fullscreen*

`/_NODETITLE_/teaser` -> node rendered as display mode *Teaser*

Any ideas?
Thanks.

:-) AK